# Black border: Image smoothing using Gaussian filter mask in Open CV

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, gaussian

I am trying to implement a naıve convolution using a 2D filter mask(Gaussian filter). I am doing it in open CV. Problem is that, I am getting some black border around the edge of the image. I am using the following code:

```
void naive(int maskSize,Mat img1){


int i,j,k,l,centreOfMask,w,h,newImageWidth,newImageHeight;


double sigma,summation = 0.0;
float a,X,Y,nsum = 0;;
centreOfMask = maskSize/2;

Mat kernel = Mat::zeros(maskSize,maskSize,CV_32F);
Mat newImage = Mat::zeros(img1.size(),CV_32F);
sigma = (maskSize - 1.0) / (2.0 * 2.575);
for(i = 0; i< maskSize;i++){
    for(j = 0;j<maskSize;j++){
        X = abs(centreOfMask-i);
        Y = abs(centreOfMask-j);

        a =(1.0/(2.0* (M_PI) * pow(sigma,2.0))) * exp(-(pow(X,2.0) + pow(Y,2.0)) / (2.0 * pow(sigma,2.0)));
        kernel.at<float>(i,j)=a;
        summation = summation + a;

    }
}
kernel = kernel/summation;

Size s;
s = img1.size();
w = s.width;
h = s.height;
newImageWidth = w - centreOfMask;
newImageHeight = h - centreOfMask;

for(i=centreOfMask;i<newImageWidth;i++){
    for(j = centreOfMask; j < newImageHeight; j++){
        for(k= -centreOfMask;k<centreOfMask+1;k++){
            for(l = -centreOfMask; l < centreOfMask+1;l++){
                nsum = nsum + (int)(img1.at<uchar>(i+k,j+l)) * kernel.at<float>(k+centreOfMask,l+centreOfMask);
            }
        }
        newImage.at<float>(i,j)=nsum;
        nsum=0;

    }

}

newImage.convertTo(newImage, CV_8U);
imshow("hellow",newImage);
waitKey(0);

}
```

I get the following output(first one is the input image, second is the filtered image):
[image]
[image]
I have used mask size 7x7. There is a built in method of openCV called filter2d, when I use that, I do not get that boundary. Can somebody explain the reason? How can I avoid this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your parameters for `filter2d` are similar? Your pictures are not visible, by the way.

Comment: since your start your computation at coordinate locations `centreOfMask` you dont set the pixel values for the boundary. Since you set the values to 0 in intialization, that boundary is black ;) That's a common problem in filtering, you have to decide yourself how you handle the border parts where the filter mask goes out of the image!